# spring-boot can't get hazelcast.sessionId cookie with secure and http-only

Tags: spring-boot, session, tomcat, cookies, hazelcast

Using spring-boot 2.17 with hazelcast 3.11 and tomcat 9.0.39.

I have set a WebFilter bean:

```
    @Bean
    public WebFilter webFilter(HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance) {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("instance-name", hazelcastInstance.getName());
        properties.put("sticky-session", "false");
        properties.put("map-name", "httpSessions");
        properties.put("cookie-path", "/");
        properties.put("cookie-secure", true);
        properties.put("cookie-http-only", true);
        return new WebFilter(properties);
    }
```

But the hazelcast.sessionId cookie doesn't end up with secure=true and http-only=true.

Any workaround perhaps?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put boolean properties with string values:

```
properties.put("cookie-secure", "true");
properties.put("cookie-http-only", "true");
```

In case you wonder its cause, this is because of `java.util.Properties#getProperty` behavior used by WebFilter internally. It looks like:

```
public String getProperty(String key) {
  Object oval = map.get(key);
  String sval = (oval instanceof String) ? (String)oval : null;
  ...
}
```

hence behaves like your boolean values are null.

Comment: Thank you, it works. Now I started to use @EnableHazelcastHttpSession which makes I can use HazelcastSessionRepository. Any idea how I can set the cookie properties without the hazelcast WebFilter? As using hazelcast WebFilter changes the session object to be HazelcastSession instead of spring MapSession and session doesn't timeout

Comment: And if it's not asking too much, if it's possible to set sticky session to false without using hazelcast WebFilter

Comment: Are you trying to use @EnableHazelcastHttpSession and WebFilter together? If so, you shouldn't because both are different modules trying to establish the same goal: Using the same session store for different application containers. I don't think they will work as expected at the same time and if there is any reason to do so. So, first I suggest you to follow the guides here on https://guides.hazelcast.org/home under `tutorials` section and see which one among the three of them (Spring Session, WebFilter or TomcatSessionManager) fits well into your use case.

Comment: No, I was just trying to use @EnableHazelcastHttpSession now instead of WebFilter as I had issues with sessions not timing out as they should. Seems I got it all working now, thanks.